# Awk Comparsion in multiple files

Tags: awk

I have 2 files:

`file1`:

```
1,apple  
2,mango  
3,banana  
44,orange
```

`file2`:

```
1,apple  
22,  
31,xyz  
2,man  
3,banana  
44,oran   
44,orange
```

I need to find the differences from both the files using column 1 and checking column 2. I don't want to use `$0` as its printing the lines which of 1st file which are not present in `file2` too.

Result output should be printed in `file3` as :

```
2,mango,man  
44,orange,oran
```

Mango is from `file1` (column 2) and man is from `file2` (column2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Slightly different awk:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","}($1 in a) && a[$1]!=$2{print $1,a[$1],$2}{a[$1]=$2}' file1 file2
2,mango,man  
44,orange,oran
```

Explained:

```
awk 'BEGIN {
    FS=OFS=","            # set separators
}
($1 in a) && a[$1]!=$2 {  # if the id is in a and $2s differ   (may occur only after file1 
    print $1,a[$1],$2     # output                              is already hashed into a)
}
{
    a[$1]=$2              # hash to a
}' file1 file2
```

Comment: Thanks its working as expected, could it be possible to provide me details on this script,

Comment: Hi James, I am facing one issue in case file 2 is having 2 rows like 44,oran
44,orange  then i am getting result like :- 44,orange,oran
44,oran,orange.   which is not my expected result could it be possible if we can exculde such results and write them to other file

Comment: Please update to the original examples the expected result when one file has 2 identical ids.

Comment: Updated file2 pls run ur cmd and you can see descripencies

Comment: The problem is very obvious when data is indexed with duplicate ids. The question is _what is your expected output in such case_? What is the expected output if there are duplicates in file1? How about file2? How about if both files have duplicates? Print first entry? Print second entry?

Comment: If the expected output you have right now remains, add `delete a[$1];next` after the `print` line.

Comment: Hi , i am sure the duplicates will be in file 2 as file1 is already been produced after select uniq entries for coloumn 1.  So we need to handle the file 2 duplicates. Expected output should be everything works as per ur previous solution apart from  the duplicates in file 2 should nt come in file 3 and will be writed in file 4 . So that those enties will be reported as data duplicate issues.  Kindly let me know if more info needed

Comment: My fix presented in the comments is still valid.

Answer (score 3):

Following `awk` may help you in same.

```
awk -F, 'FNR==NR{a[$1]=$0;b[$2];next} ($1 in a) && !($2 in b){print a[$1],$2}' OFS=,   Input_file1  Input_file2
```

In case you want to take output into a file named file3 then add `> file3` at last of into above command.